# Portable python with Kivy designer

Tags: python, kivy

I'm operating on a windows 7 machine but because I don't have admin rights, I needed to use a portable version of python.
I'm following these two tutorials:
https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#
https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer

I was able to get kivy installed to my portable python path and I'm running into trouble with the 2nd tutorials

```
garden install filebrowser
```

I checked my installed modules and it says that I have kivy-garden:

```
['argh==0.26.1', 'docutils==0.12', 'gitdb==0.6.4', 'gitpython==1.0.1', 'jedi==0.9.0', 'kivy-garden==0.1.4', 'kivy.deps.glew== 0.1.4', 'kivy.deps.gstreamer==0.1.5', 'kivy.deps.sdl2==0.1.12', 'kivy==1.9.1', 'lxml==3.3.4', 'matplotlib==1.3.1', 'numpy==1.8.1', 'pandas==0.11.0', 'pathtools==0.1.2', 'pil==1.1.7', 'pip==8.0.2', 'py2exe==0.6.9', 'pycairo==1.8.10', 'pygame==1.9.1','pygments==2.1', 'pygobject==2.28.3', 'pygoocanvas==0.14.2', 'pygtk==2.24.0', 'pygtksourceview==2.10.1', 'pyodbc==3.0.7', 'pyparsing==2.0.1', 'pypiwin32==219', 'pyrsvg==2.32.1', 'pyserial==2.7', 'pywin32==218', 'pyyaml==3.11', 'requests==2.9.1', 'scipy==0.13.3', 'setuptools==19.4', 'six==1.10.0', 'smmap==0.9.0', 'watchdog==0.8.3', 'wheel==0.26.0']
```

I tried to launch the designer's main.py without the file browser and I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Sources\Portable_Python_2.7.6.1\kivy-designer-master\main.py", line 2, in <module>
     from designer.app import DesignerApp
   File "C:\Sources\Portable_Python_2.7.6.1\kivy-designer-master\designer\app.py", line 28, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.filebrowser import FileBrowser
 ImportError: No module named filebrowser
```

Which it appears I cannot do unless I install the filebrowser.

Has anyone run into this before? I don't care if I don't have a file browser, I really just want the Kivy Designer to work because I'm still learning Python GUI modeling and having a designer would make it so much easier. Many of the tutorials I've looked at talk about using the Kivy.bat, but I have searched everywhere and when you using the installation on windows, a Kivy.bat is never created.

Comment: Just so you know, the designer is really experimental software, and you could hit a lot of problems even if you get it working. However, one reason it doesn't get much focus is that writing the gui code manually is easier than you probably think, so don't be afraid to do it. Also, the kivy.bat probably doesn't exist any more now that we changed to a wheel distribution method.

Comment: Just try: `garden install FileBrowser`

Comment: When I try garden install FileBrowser I get an error about invalid syntax at install...

@inclement, I'm really not that good at GUI and I'm use to using things that allow me to drag and drop so I can understand the code more... I'm a DB guy as a background, which is why I'm trying to get more python exp... I can do a lot of my db stuff without needing a DB using python.